# Не получается прикрепить обработчик событий обработчик событий к программно созданным элементам

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Я создаю Grid каждый элемент которого имеет пару кнопок, и хочу по клику на одну из кнопок производить различные манипуляции. 
Вот xaml:

```
<GridView Name="list" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,90,0,0">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                <Grid Background="#7F9BD1D4" Height="Auto" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Name="Car" Grid.Column="0" Content="Машина"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#7F9BD1D4"
                            Foreground="White" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    <Button Name="Cat"  Grid.Column="1" Content="Кошка"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding Act}"
                            Background="#7F9BD1D4" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Title}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Вот великий код

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Car.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

И, собственно, проблема... [image: Ошибка]

Comment: А если вместо `Car` использовать `((Button)sender)`?

Comment: ............ Я просто sender писал... баттон не допер написать... Спасибо)

Comment: Окей, тогда опубликую как ответ.

Comment: @VladD Подскажи пожалуйста, мне нужно чтобы по тыку на вторую кнопку у меня на всплывающем окне выводилось изображение этого элемента GridView (`<Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />`)  Я не могу придумать, как вывести изображение с Итем в котором находится кнопка...

Comment: Сходу не соображу, это неочевидно. Думаю, стоит задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что имена наподобие `Car` видны в C#-коде лишь для элементов, которые добавляются на этапе компиляции. Для динамически определяемых шаблонов имён нет (например, потому, что шаблон может быть применён несколько раз).

Самый простой путь — ваш `sender` будет по сути элементом, по которому произошёл клик. То есть, вам достаточно написать

```
((Button)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```